# Stored value from soap __getLastRequest() echos but won't register in array

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, variables, soap

I've got a problem that seems particularly odd (to me at least).  So I'm using a soap API to interact with a program that (among other things) creates user groups and assigns users to them.  I need to create a group and then assign a user to it using two different soap functions; this requires me to store the returned variable from one soap api call and input it into the next (see below).

```
$value = $SOAP->addOrganisation($params);
$group=$SOAP->__getLastResponse();
echo "<br/>Group: ".$group."<br/>";
$params=array('SID'=>$sid, 'user_id'=>$user, 'organisation_id'=>$group, 'insertedby'=>1);
$value= $SOAP->addUserToOrganisation($params);
```

Straight-forward right?
**But here's where it gets interesting:** the variable $group echos what I'm expecting but seems not to work in the soap call `addUserToOrganisation`.  The returned value says that it ran fine, however `addUserToOrganisation` doesn't end up carrying out its task (actually adding the user to the group).

**Conjectures anticipated:** 
(Stuff I've already guessed at)

*Maybe it's a glitch in the function `addUserToOrganisation`?*

That would make sense and I thought the same.  However when I hard-coded a number in there (even when it was the exact same number the variable would have echoed), it works just fine.

*Maybe the API doesn't play nicely with variables in that spot in the array?*

I actually reset the variable manually with a number (see below) and it worked no problem.

```
$value = $SOAP->addOrganisation($params);
$group=$SOAP->__getLastResponse();
echo "<br/>Group: ".$group."<br/>";
    $group=55;
    echo "<br/>Group: ".$group."<br/>";
$params=array('SID'=>$sid, 'user_id'=>$user, 'organisation_id'=>$group, 'insertedby'=>1);
$value= $SOAP->addUserToOrganisation($params);
```

*Any stray spaces attached to that variable?*

None that I can see.

*...Maybe you pissed off the gnomes inside your computer that make it work?*

Quite possibly but they've put up with my abuse for so long, why the sudden uprising?

**My best guess:**  As far as I can tell, there just seems that there is something inherently unacceptable about using the output of __getLastRequest(), even though it just looks like a regular old number when echoed.  I don't know if not all strings are equal or something but if any of you have an idea, I'd really appreciate it.

(just watch, it turns out to somehow be some dumb syntax error)

Anyway, thanks in advance

Comment: You say that echo $group does what you expect.  What is that? Can you please edit the question and show what happens when you `var_dump($group);` - the problem is almost certainly an issue with the structure / contents of that variable.

Comment: @cale_b  Yea, I probably should have included that info.  When $group is echoed, it simply echos the group's ID number.  When I did a var_dump to it, I got this: `string(300) "82" `.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: have you tried `echo "<br/>Group: ".htmlentities($group,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')."<br/>";` because the result of __getLastREsponse() should be an XML string meaning that dispolayed within HTML does only show you the XML tag values and not the tags themselves...

Comment: @MikaëlDELSOL It seems that you're onto something!  As you were no doubt expecting, I had the following echoed back at me: `Group: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns:addOrganisationResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.axis.openmeetings.apache.org"><ns:return>83</ns:return></ns:addOrganisationResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>`  Is there an elegant way to just store the XML tag values in a variable without the tags themselves?  Many thanks!

Comment: Yes.  Look at the php method simplexml_load_string - see this answer for some tips

Comment: You're not passing trace=1 to the constructor so `__getLastRequest()` and `__getLastResponse()` won't even work as expected. If you got a SOAP response of `55` that's not valid xml...